# How to encapsulate HTML and JavaScript in Angular view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very large piece of markup, which is wrapped by `ng-controller`, it looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <script>
        // MyController is bootstraped with current_item_data to save additional work of loading data using service, etc.
        var current_item_data = <?= json_encode($this->view->current_item_data) ?>;
        var current_parent_item_data = <?= json_encode($this->view->current_parent_item_data) ?>;
    </script>

    <!-- large markup comes here -->
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that I want to reuse that controller multiple times in the same page, e.g.:

```
<div>
    <!-- * included by php template engine -->
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <script>
            var current_item_data = []; /* holds item #1 data */
            var current_parent_item_data = []; /* holds parent item #1 data */
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- /included template -->
    <!-- * included by php template engine -->
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <script>
            var current_item_data = []; /* holds item #2 data */
            var current_parent_item_data = []; /* holds parent item #2 data */
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- /included template -->
</div>
```

In `MyController` initialization logic, I have this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.currentItemData = $window.current_item_data;

    $scope.parentItemData = $window.current_parent_item_data;

}]);
```

I think you see the problem here, each time `MyController` is instantiated, it uses the same global variable, and it's not working as expected.

And yes, I'm looking for any workaround as I can't refactor the codebase at the moment.

Comment: Looks like you want to re-use some html+logic, which seems a perfect job for a directive

Comment: @devqon, AFAIK, Angular won't compile code wrapped by `<script></script>` within template?

Comment: Then don't do wrapped `<script>` tags in your template. Do something like `<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="init(<?= json_encode($this->view->current_item_data) ?>)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have `<script>` tags inside your template. Instead you can use angular's `ng-init` directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController"
     ng-init="init(<?= json_encode($this->view->current_item_data) ?>, <?= json_encode($this->view->current_parent_item_data) ?>)">

</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.currentItemData = [];
    $scope.parentItemData = [];

    $scope.init = function(currentItemData, parentItemData) {
        $scope.currentItemData = currentItemData;
        $scope.parentItemData = parentItemData;
    }

}]);
```

Comment: It's strange, but when I try to inject data like this, Angular throws: `Unexpected end of expression: init([{`

Comment: Make sure the quotes are correctly escaped etc. You can test it with a simple string if it works

Comment: This answer as-is would result in a leaking attribute. `ng-init="init({"foo":"bar"})"` due to quotes not being escaped.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use routeProvider .. you can assign controller based on pages. Hope this will help..

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fA968/272/)** here

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    // set up routing
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/dashboard.html',
        controller : 'mainCtrl',
        title : 'Home'
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
        controller : 'AboutController',
        title : 'About'
    }).when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/contact.html',
        controller : 'ContactController',
        title : 'Contact'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>AD Operation Reports</title>


</head>

<body >
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need to use same controller logic.

Comment: You can use the same logic: just specify the same controller. Also the routes can use `resolve` to inject different values into each controller instance if you need to parametrise them.